# Multiple controllers in angularJS throws error

Tags: angularjs

My code is like this

controller.js

```
angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers', []).controller('ReadOnlyController', [
    '$scope', 'rateRequestService', 'rePrintAllService', 'rePrintService', 'voidShipmentService', 'updateTruckNoService', 'messageModalService', '$modal', 'FileUploader',
    function ($scope, rateRequestService, rePrintAllService, rePrintService, voidShipmentService, updateTruckNoService, messageModalService, $modal, FileUploader) {
      // my logic

    }
]);

angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers').controller('GenericRateRequestCtrl', function ($scope, addressService) {
  // my logic
});
```

app.js

```
angular.module('RateRequestApp', [
    'RateRequestApp.services',
    'RateRequestApp.controllers',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'angular-loading-bar',
    'textAngular',
    'angularFileUpload'
]);
```

HTML

```
<body ng-app="RateRequestApp" ng-controller="GenericRateRequestCtrl">
</body>
```

everything looks okay to me, but this throws an error

```
 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'GenericRateRequestCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

Can any one point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you load the `<script src="controller.js"></script>` into your html?

Comment: @iulian Yes, I have. it look like error is something like it. as I have tried adding other working controllers to the page and it still throws same error.

Comment: can you replicate this issue in a plunker/fiddle? This really is strange, but at the same time interesting what causes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript code, change from `RateRequestApp.controllers` to `RateRequestApp`

EXAMPLE:

```
angular.module('RateRequestApp', []).controller('ReadOnlyController', [
    '$scope', 'rateRequestService', 'rePrintAllService', 'rePrintService', 'voidShipmentService', 'updateTruckNoService', 'messageModalService', '$modal', 'FileUploader',
    function ($scope, rateRequestService, rePrintAllService, rePrintService, voidShipmentService, updateTruckNoService, messageModalService, $modal, FileUploader) {
      // my logic

    }
]);

angular.module('RateRequestApp').controller('GenericRateRequestCtrl', function ($scope, addressService) {
  // my logic
});
```

Demo:

http://jsbin.com/sunacagina/1/

Comment: @Athul Did you changed it in html ?

Comment: Read the question carefully, there is already `ng-app="RateRequestApp"` on body tag.

Comment: @Adeel I don't get it. What to change in HTML?

Comment: @Athul There is problem with your injector `addressService` , Either remove it, or if you want to use that service, define either in same module, or inject the module in case if it's from other module.

Answer (score -1):

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sfekLmpe/1/)

Create variable with your module and use it after:

```
var appCtrls = angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers',[]); 

appCtrls.controller('ReadOnlyController', [
    '$scope', 'rateRequestService', 'rePrintAllService', 'rePrintService', 'voidShipmentService', 'updateTruckNoService', 'messageModalService', '$modal', 'FileUploader',
    function ($scope, rateRequestService, rePrintAllService, rePrintService, voidShipmentService, updateTruckNoService, messageModalService, $modal, FileUploader) {
      // my logic

    }
]);

appCtrls.controller('GenericRateRequestCtrl', function ($scope, addressService) {
  // my logic
});
```

Comment: @Athul, I fix answer, pls check it